# Butane Burning Color

Tags: physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

Why does Butane burn blue? From my (very) basic understanding of chemistry, carbon and hydrogen do not burn blue, their radiation spectra are different-so why should the combination burn blue?
Please elaborate as much as possible, about bonds, orbitals, electrons, and the like!

Answer (score 3):

The blue flame from butane (or many other hydrocarbons) is due to the complete combustion of the gas.  From the Wikipedia article [Flame color](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flame#Flame_color) it mentions,

> In the most common type of flame, hydrocarbon flames, the most important factor determining color is oxygen supply and the extent of fuel-oxygen pre-mixing, which determines the rate of combustion and thus the temperature and reaction paths, thereby producing different color hues.

Specifically, making the link to the common tool in the laboratory, a Bunsen Burner, which typically has two 'types of flame (as seen below):

[image]

[Image Source](https://wsc11sci.wikispaces.com/Combustion) - which states that:

> The Bunsen Burners we use at school use a mixture of alkane gases like propane and butane

The yellow flame is from an incomplete combustion, producing $\ce{CO}$ and the colour is due to (according to the Wikipedia article):

> incandescence of very fine soot particles that are produced in the flame.

With more oxygen, a complete combustion of butane is possible (without the soot):

$$\ce{2C4H10 +13O2 -> 8CO2 + 10H2O}$$

Which provides

> enough energy to excite and ionize gas molecules in the flame.

and the blue flame colour is due to the

> emission of excited molecular radicals in the flame, which emit most of their light well below ~565 nanometers in the blue and green regions of the visible spectrum.

Answer (score 3):

The blue color is the Swan lines' emission of $\ce{C2}$.  Rather than acetylene diradical it is more likely to be the olefin singlet dicarbene,

[image]